# Grub2 disable right arrow booting

Tags: grub2, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes when I turn on the computer I want to go to a different boot option than usual in grub, so I use the up or down arrow key to get to it. However since they are close to the right-arrow key, I sometimes misclick, which is mildly annoying. So how do I disable the right arrow key in the grub menu?

Comment: Just press `Ctrl+N` or similar instead to avoid this:   https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137323/grub2-without-arrow-keys#137326

Comment: Can't believe this is enabled by default... surely more people are mis-hitting that key than actually using it for its intended purpose.