# I cannot select a GRUB option because of buggy keyboard inputs

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, boot-loader

#### Problem

I want to start Ubuntu in recovery mode because it won't boot normally.

I have three options in my GRUB selection screen:
[image: grub selection menu]
If I press the down arrow on my keyboard, the selection moves all the way to the bottom of the list (Windows 10), and if I press the up arrow it goes all the way to the top (Ubuntu).

Another thing which happens is that if I press the arrow keys a couple times the computer appears to crash, or it stops handling keyboard inputs at all.

#### Details

- I'm running GRUB v2.02
- I recently ran the boot-repair utility which reinstalled GRUB, and have done this a couple times, each time with the same result
- Here's [a link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KFQ35pNvG8) to a Boot Repair summary

#### Question

How can I can start Ubuntu in recovery mode?

Comment: Have you run `sudo update-grub` ? Its almost as if you have Advanced options a a title, but not the sub-menu items under which should be recovery mode & second kernel & its recovery mode. Did you make any other changes to grub? or grub scripts? If so you may need total reinstall of grub, but that will depend on if UEFI or BIOS version.

Comment: I've reinstalled GRUB twice using the boot-repair utility with recommended options

Comment: Post link to Summary Report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: Are you using a keyboard that is special in some way? For example, some gaming keyboards implement N-Key Rollover (the capability to recognize an unlimited number of keys pressed simultaneously) by appearing on the USB bus as multiple keyboards, to work around USB HID protocol limitation. If poorly implemented, that might cause problems with USB keyboard support of the system firmware, which is used by GRUB.

Comment: @telcoM No my keyboard is nothing special. I assumed it wasn't a problem with the keyboard itself because when booting I to windows I have no issues with the keyboard. I'll try a different keyboard later today.

Comment: @oldfred I added a pastebin link in the details

Comment: I do not know LVM. But I see a 3TB drive, formatted MBR. Drives over 2TB require gpt. So you have converted 3TB drive to 2TB. If you convert to gpt, it will erase it. Windows requires UEFI install if gpt, and partitions/structure is a lot different. It looks like you have UEFI hardware, so could reinstall Windows & Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode, but make sure you have good backups.

Comment: @oldfred this is all interesting info to me, I have been running with this setup for about 4 years so I don't believe having an MBR formatted drive is the issue which is causing the issue I'm asking about in my question. I am definitely considering reinstalling with GPT/UEFI.

Comment: Same behaviour with [`Ctrl+p` and `Ctrl+n`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/137326/332764)?

Comment: Report did not show fstab. Is LVM encrypted? Best to decrypt before running Boot-Repair, so it can see / (root) and any settings there. Also decrypt required to run repairs.

Comment: @Freddy just tried Ctrl+p and Ctrl+n, the results are the same

Comment: @oldfred LVM isn't encrypted. It's interesting that fstab was missing; I'll investigate if I can get it to show in the report

Comment: It may be a stupid question but can you get into Ubuntu to modify your boot menu?

Comment: @PhilipCouling Not a stupid question at all. As I explained in the question, I can't boot Ubuntu normally which is why I want to start it in recovery mode. However, one thing which I will be looking into will be to mount the boot partition from within a live OS and edit the boot menu from there to fix the Ubuntu issue and potentially boot it up.

Comment: Could this be because of missing intel microcode firmware? I experienced something similar once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by updating my BIOS.

My motherboard is a "Fatal1ty AB350 Gaming-ITX/ac" and I updated the BIOS version from 5.70 to 6.60

Comment: Worked for me on ASUS TUF B450M-PRO GAMING, I updated my BIOS from v2006 to v3604 and now the keyboard works fine in GRUB.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to the other buttons of the keyboard, then once you are on Ubuntu press the letter "e", go down to

```
linux   /BOOT/ubuntu........ro quiet splash ....
initrd  /BOOT/......
```

remove "**quiet splash**" and any thing like "**${vt_handoff}**" and replace it with
"**recovery nomodeset  dis_ucode_ldr**" and press F10 or ctrl+x.

recovery: boot into recovery.

nomodeset: disable graphic drivers.

dis_ucode_ldr is disable microcode. look@https://wiki.debian.org/Microcode

After F10, you will boot into recovery mode.

Comment: This would not work as I was getting duplicated keyboard inputs within GRUB's editor making adding these lines impossible

Comment: Then your problem could be connected with hardware. Try to use another keyboard, or update the firmware (BIOS) or reinstall it if that possible.

Answer (score 0):

This issue began happening to me due to a BIOS and CPU upgrade; I definitely changed no GRUB settings.

It seems to be a bad interaction between GRUB and some BIOS keyboard drivers.

I'm stuck with a puke-awful MSI motherboard and they have no working BIOS version compatible with this CPU. However, I did find a workaround:

This motherboard still features a PS/2 port, and I still have a spare PS/2 keyboard. The PS/2 keyboard works correctly to access the recovery console.

If you're desperate, another workaround would be to temporarily put the boot device in a different computer.